# Windows 7 32bit usual install size?

Tags: windows-7, installation

I was wondering what could be the usual installation size for Windows 7 (32bit, without any extras).

Comment: Mine is 17.7, all updates applied. auto page file (2gb ram installed), 1 restore point and hibernation turned off. Also ran cleanmanager.

Comment: [According to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements) it is "16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)"

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be 12.2gb for me (with 2520-3780mb automatic pagefile size and no system restore)

Comment: I have 17.4 Gigabytes, with a download folder of almost half a gigabyte, no hibernation, no System Restore Internet Explorer turned off, Firefox installed, with many extra software(s), including SysInsternals whole suit. I am only running 1.5 GB of RAM.